# Java ignoring if-else statements

Tags: java

My assignment for school is to write a program in java that accepts a four-digit entry from System.in.read(); and calculates whether or not it is a leap year, and then tells the user whether or not it is a leap year, then presents the option to restart the program. Also, if the user enters a year before 1582 it will tell them of the error, followed by the program reset option.

```
public class RevisedLeapYear {
    public static void main(String args[])
    throws java.io.IOException {

    char restartChoice = 'y';
    int readCh, year=0, i;
    boolean isLeapYear;

    while(restartChoice == 'y' || restartChoice == 'Y'){
        System.out.print("Enter target year: ");
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)//start for
        {
            readCh = (int)System.in.read();
            switch(i) //start switch
            {//converts in to 4 digits
                case 0: year = (int)((readCh - 48) * 1000); break;
                case 1: year = year + (int) ((readCh - 48) * 100); break;
                case 2: year = year + (int) ((readCh - 48) * 10); break;
                case 3: year = year + (int) (readCh - 48);
            }//end switch
    }//end for
        isLeapYear = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0));
                if(isLeapYear == true && year > 1581){
                System.out.println(year + " is a Leap Year! What a time to be alive! \nPress Enter to continue.");
            }
                else if(isLeapYear == false && year > 1581){
                System.out.println(year + " is not a Leap Year... how unfortunate. \nPress Enter to continue.");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("There are no leap years before 1582! \nPress Enter to continue.");
            }
    readCh = System.in.read(); // Clear the carriage return in the buffer
    readCh = System.in.read(); // Clear the linefeed in the buffer

    System.out.print("Reset program? y/n \n");
    restartChoice=(char)System.in.read();

    }              
}
}
```

But for some reason, when I restart the program and enter a year, it will say its before 1582 no matter what, and display all lines until the reset prompt without stopping.

```
Enter target year: 2004
2004 is a Leap Year! What a time to be alive! 
Press Enter to continue.

Reset program? y/n 
y
Enter target year: 2003
There are no leap years before 1582! 
Press Enter to continue.
Reset program? y/n 
n
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 21 seconds)
```

EDIT: Fixed it on my own. The problem was that the year wasn't being cleared from the buffer. I added this to the last line.

```
year=(int)System.in.read();
```

Making this the end product.

```
public class RevisedLeapYear {
    public static void main(String args[])
    throws java.io.IOException {

    char restartChoice = 'y';
    int readCh, year=0, i;
    boolean isLeapYear;

    while(restartChoice == 'y' || restartChoice == 'Y'){
        System.out.print("Enter target year: ");
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)//start for
        {
            readCh = (int)System.in.read();
            switch(i) //start switch
            {//converts in to 4 digits
                case 0: year = (int)((readCh - 48) * 1000); break;
                case 1: year = year + (int) ((readCh - 48) * 100); break;
                case 2: year = year + (int) ((readCh - 48) * 10); break;
                case 3: year = year + (int) (readCh - 48);
            }//end switch
    }//end for
        isLeapYear = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0));
                if(isLeapYear == true && year > 1581){
                System.out.println(year + " is a Leap Year! What a time to be alive! \nPress Enter to continue.");
            }
                else if(isLeapYear == false && year > 1581){
                System.out.println(year + " is not a Leap Year... how unfortunate. \nPress Enter to continue.");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("There are no leap years before 1582! \nPress Enter to continue.");
            }
    readCh = System.in.read(); // Clear the carriage return in the buffer
    readCh = System.in.read(); // Clear the linefeed in the buffer

    System.out.print("Reset program? y/n \n");
    restartChoice=(char)System.in.read();
    year=(int)System.in.read();

    }              
}
}
```

Comment: Why calculate anything if the target year is `1580` for example?

Comment: The problem is that you are forgetting to read the newline after `restartChoice` - a char value `13`. This is taken to be the first digit of the year, initializing the year to `-35000`. Print the year and you'll see.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. The problem is reproducible, and the error is not a "simple typo" but a logic error.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with handling of ends-of-lines.

You have forgotten that **each input the user enters is followed by an end-of-line**. This can be just carriage return, or a carriage return and a linefeed.

Your program reads in four bytes. When the user enters those bytes, he also presses <kbd>Return</kbd>. That inserts a byte to the stream.

Because you told the user to "Press Enter to continue", the user presses <kbd>Return</kbd> again. That inserts another byte to the stream.

You then clear two bytes from the stream. You assume that you removed a carriage return and a line feed. But in fact you just removed the carriage return that came after the year, and the additional one that was pressed.

Now you ask the user for `y` or `n`. But to enter those, the user clicks both <kbd>y</kbd> and <kbd>Return</kbd>. So he enters **two** characters to the stream. `restartChoice` only gets one of them - the `y` or the `n`, but the carriage return is still in the input stream. You then go back to the head of the loop, print the prompt and start the `for` loop. At this point, you read the carriage return. Only then you start reading the next year.

So if your next year string is `2003`, what you actually get in your loop is <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. Your year calculation becomes `(13-48)*1000 + (50-48)*100 + (48-48)*10 + (48-48)` - which is a very small number because the first term is negative.

So it tells you the year you entered is before 1580.

- Always use a `Reader` to read text. Don't try to read raw bytes and convert them yourself. For one thing, you don't know if your machine will enter only a return or both a return and a line feed at the end of each line. When you are more proficient in programming, you can try to write an input handler for these situation. But this is not really necessary - you already have various `Reader`s you can use, or `Scanner` which is excellent for beginners.
- When you want to interpret a number, always make sure that it is made up of valid digits.
- There is also the matter of bad logic. You shouldn't be using a `for` with a `switch` inside it. Since you already write each operation separately in the switch, you might as well remove the loop altogether and check the characters straight on:

  ```
  System.out.print("Enter target year: ");
  readCh = (int) System.in.read();
  year = (int) ((readCh - 48) * 1000);
  readCh = (int) System.in.read();
  year = year + (int) ((readCh - 48) * 100);
  readCh = (int) System.in.read();
  year = year + (int) ((readCh - 48) * 10);
  readCh = (int) System.in.read();
  year = year + (int) (readCh - 48);
  ```

  Isn't this simpler than a switch in a loop?
- And you should first check if the year is greater than 1581, and only if it is, check if it is leap or not.

Comment: I would say this is a very detailed observation and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged your codes a bit and replaced the `System.in.read()` with Scanner. Everything works normally after that. The problem lies in your `System.in.read()` statement.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{  
    char restartChoice = 'y';
    int year=0;
    boolean isLeapYear;
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(restartChoice == 'y' || restartChoice == 'Y'){
        System.out.print("Enter target year: ");
        year = Integer.parseInt(scn.nextLine());

        isLeapYear = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0));

        if(isLeapYear && year > 1581)
            System.out.println(year + " is a Leap Year! What a time to be alive! \nPress Enter to continue.");    
        else if(!isLeapYear && year > 1581)
            System.out.println(year + " is not a Leap Year... how unfortunate. \nPress Enter to continue.");            
        else
            System.out.println("There are no leap years before 1582! \nPress Enter to continue.");

        System.out.print("Reset program? y/n \n");
        restartChoice = scn.nextLine().charAt(0);
    }              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't with your if else statement but rather with How System.in.read() is reading it in a second time because it is not reading it in a second time.

You might want to look at how to use Scanner.